# How could I calculate an expression across the slices of a 3D-array?

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I have calculated this hc index for every 24 values of a 24x24 square matrix (a). It returns a vector (hc) with 24 values.

```
hc<-vector("numeric",24L)
for (i in 1:24) {
  hc[i]<- -sum((c(a[,i])/colSums(a)[i])*log((c(a[,i])/colSums(a)[i]), base = 2))
  }
```

I want to calculate this for each of the 1000 matrices of an array and don't know exactly how to proceed (a function?, another nested "for" statement?...). And get 1000, 24length vectors. One for each matrix in the array. I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach, if you actually have an array:

```r
# Simplified version of your function
f <- function(x) -sum(x / sum(x) * log2(x / sum(x)))

set.seed(1)
n <- 1000

matrices <- replicate(n, matrix(runif(24 ^ 2), nrow = 24))
str(matrices)
#>  num [1:24, 1:24, 1:1000] 0.266 0.372 0.573 0.908 0.202 ...

result <- apply(matrices, c(2, 3), f)
str(result)
#>  num [1:24, 1:1000] 4.36 4.36 4.37 4.36 4.34 ...
```

If your matrices are in a list:

```r
matrix_list <- lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) matrices[, , i])
list_result <- lapply(matrix_list, apply, 2, f)
str(head(list_result))
#> List of 6
#>  $ : num [1:24] 4.36 4.36 4.37 4.36 4.34 ...
#>  $ : num [1:24] 4.43 4.32 4.31 4.4 4.37 ...
#>  $ : num [1:24] 4.26 4.21 4.31 4.24 4.24 ...
#>  $ : num [1:24] 4.31 4.36 4.27 4.32 4.35 ...
#>  $ : num [1:24] 4.39 4.27 4.35 4.29 4.22 ...
#>  $ : num [1:24] 4.25 4.42 4.19 4.32 4.33 ...
```

Created on 2018-03-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Many thanks for the rapid response. I now trying to integrate both responses, since both are usefull. I think the simplification fo the formula is not exactly what I wanted since I wanted values in colums divided by the sum of that colum (all summed later). Your solution to apply the function across an array is very useful. many many thanks!

Comment: Note that since the function `f` here is applied to each column `x`, the `sum(x)` is actually the sum of the values in that column. Which should be what you wanted? It's essentially the same if you had written `sum(a[, i])` in the loop.

Comment: I see... you are indicating this with the second argument of apply ( c(**2**,3) ), isn't it? wow! This really simplifies my life!

Comment: That's right. And if you wanted to calculate this same function over the rows rather than the columns, all you would need to do is change the second argument of apply to `c(1, 3)`.

Comment: And what if  I had to combine by-rows and by-columns calculations?? for example, I have now to calculate _ldhc_ with `for (i in 1:24) {ldhc[i]<-(colSums(a)[i]/sum(a))*2^hc[i]}`, where I have the sum of the column _i_ in the matrix _a_, and the sum of all the matrix _a_. 2^hc is the reciprocal of the former calculation (log2), so hc is a 24x1000 matrix.

Comment: Ah, it gets a bit trickier to keep working with arrays then, but I think something like this should work: `sweep(apply(matrices, 3, colSums), 2, apply(matrices, 3, sum), "/") * 2 ^ hc`

Comment: Thinking on this a bit further, a much more readable solution would probably be like this: `g <- function(x) colSums(x) / sum(x) * 2 ^ apply(x, 2, f); apply(matrices, 3, g)`, where the input to `g` is now a single matrix.

Comment: First option worked ok, but this second one is much better. Thanks.

Comment: I'm struggling with a further complication. In the f function, `log2(x/sum(x))` gives -Inf when x = 0 and I need to replace these values with 0. I have decomposed the function to 'intercept' when -Inf values are produced and substitute them. But I wonder I there is a more efficient and elegant, solution to go dirtectly to g function. Something like conditioning f function previously to making the -sum operation. I'm trying something like `f3 <- function(x) {
  -sum((x / sum(x)) * log2(x / sum(x)))
  if((log2(x/sum(x)))==-Inf) {
    log2(x/sum(x))==0
    }
    }` but not working for now.

Comment: Yes, you can do that by replacing the values in `x` where `x == 0`.  Because `log2(1) == 0` you just want to replace the zeroes with ones, essentially. These comments are getting long, so see here: https://gist.github.com/mikmart/85a5118285b1f8e4361399a1a3cb3034.

Comment: Many thanks. I have seen it there and responded. Sorry for the long comments here.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your code is very inefficient. You are calculating sum of every column in the matrix twice in every iteration. It would be better to calculate all of these at the beginning, or simply to calculate a sum when needed.

The following is more "R-like" code that should also be faster:

```
mat <- matrix(runif(100, 1, 100), nrow = 24, ncol = 24)


mat_res <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(mat)), 
    function(i, mat) {
        col <- mat[, i]
        s <- sum(col)
        sc <- col / s
        l <- log2(col) / s
        - sum(sc * l)
    }, 
    mat = mat)
```

Now, to apply this to all 1000 matrices? First, make a list of 1000 matrices:

```
list_of_mats <- lapply(1:1000, 
    function(i) matrix(runif(100, 1, 100), nrow = 24, ncol = 24))
```

Then, apply a function over each of these matrices:

```
lapply(list_of_mats, 
    function(mat) {
        ## Note that this process is the same as above!
        sapply(seq_len(ncol(mat)), 
            function(i, mat) {
                col <- mat[, i]
                s <- sum(col)
                sc <- col / s
                l <- log2(col) / s
                - sum(sc * l)
            }, 
            mat = mat)
    })
```

Comment: Many thanks for the rapid response! I'm now trying to integrate both responses, since both are very usefull. Definitively, your code is very good and of course more efficient. Your function has helped me a lot. I'm now trying if your recomendation or the one in the oder response works better with an array of 1000 matrices (slices). Many many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! The best approach depends on the data structure you are working with and the output you desire.