# How to condition a part of a function

Tags: r, function, multidimensional-array

I've got this function to be applied later over 3D-arrays `f3 <- function(x) {-sum((x / sum(x)) * log2(x / sum(x)))}` and I'm trying to apply the condition that, if the second part of the function is `-Inf` (i.e. `log2(x/sum(x)=-Inf`), then this part will be `0` (i.e.     `log2(x/sum(x))=0)`. I'm trying to nest an if statement inside the function (see below) but not working for now.

```
f3 <- function(x) {
-sum((x / sum(x)) * log2(x / sum(x)))
  if((log2(x/sum(x)))==-Inf) {
log2(x/sum(x))==0
}
}
```

I use this function over an 3D-array of 1000 24x24-matrices (a) to try this I,m only using the first matrix of the array a[,,1]

```
apply (a[,,1],2,f3)
```

Any little indication would be welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: keep in mind that `=` (single equal sign) is an assignment operator equivalent to `<- `. For comparisons you should use `==` (double equal sign)

Comment: Thanks, I`ve edited the question properly. I have tried with '==' and not working.

Comment: Make your question clearer by providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1315767)

Comment: Here is the initial question and how was finally solved. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49116372/9057078

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for can be accomplished like so:

```
f3 <- function(x) {
  if(log2(x/sum(x)) == -Inf) {
    result <- 0
  } else {
    result <- -sum((x / sum(x)) * log2(x / sum(x)))
  }
  return(result)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Ive got these errors:Error in if (log2(x/sum(x)) == -Inf) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (log2(x/sum(x)) == -Inf) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: Can you share what you're inputting into `f3()` when you get these errors?

Comment: apply (a[,,1], 2, f3) , where a is just the first 24x24-matrix of an array of 1000. To try Im just using 1 matrix, Then I extend it to all the array

Comment: I see.  Change the `if` statement to `if(any(log2(x/sum(x)) == -Inf))`

Comment: The issue is: an array cannot evaluate to `-Inf`, only one of its components can.  Adding the `any()` function to your if statement will check to see if any item in the array evaluates to `-Inf`, and if so, will return `TRUE`

Comment: To try I'm using just 1 matrix. I have tried any(), but it does not seem the solution...

Comment: Ok,  Well I'm afraid to help further, I'd need to see sample data of what you're feeding in to `f3()` and what you're desired output is.

Comment: Here is the initial question and how was finally solved. https://stackoverflow.com/q/49116372/9057078

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is useful for you. Just minor changes:

```
f3 <- function(x) {
  denom <- log2(x / sum(x))
  if(denom==-Inf|is.nan(denom)) { denom <- 0}
  -sum((x / sum(x)) * denom)
}
```

NOTE: keep in mind that `=` (single equal sign) is an assignment operator equivalent to `<-` . For logical comparisons you should use `==` (double equal sign)

Comment: Thanks. Ive got these errors:Error in if (log2(x/sum(x)) == -Inf) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (log2(x/sum(x)) == -Inf) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: @shasha I think your error is produced when x takes value o, try to add an extra condition in the `if` statement to handle NaN when x=0 correctly (see update). Also remember to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1315767) so that we can help you better.

Comment: That's ok. This is the problem... I'll add reproducible examples in the future. For now I think I have to try alternative solutions

Comment: Here is the initial question and how was finally solved https://stackoverflow.com/q/49116372/9057078